# Unable to understand the following proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

**Question:** Show that (x + y)<sup>r</sup> < x<sup>r</sup> + y<sup>r</sup> whenever x and y are positive real numbers and r is a real number with 0 < r < 1.

**Solution:** Without loss of generality we can assume that **x + y = 1** [To see this, suppose we have proved the theorem with the assumption **x + y = 1**. Suppose that **x + y = t**. Then **x + y = t**. Then **(x/t) + (y/t) = 1**, which implies that **((x/t) + (y/t))<sup>r</sup> < (x/t)<sup>r</sup> + (y/t)<sup>r</sup>**. Multiplying both sides of this last equation by **t<sup>r</sup>** shows that **(x + y)<sup>r</sup> < x<sup>r</sup> + y<sup>r</sup>**.]

Assuming that **x + y = 1**, because **x and y are positive, we have 0 < x < 1 and 0 < y < 1**. Because **0 < r < 1**, it follows that **0 < 1-r < 1**, so **x<sup>1-r</sup> < 1 and y<sup>1-r</sup> < 1**. This means that **x < x<sup>r</sup> and y < y<sup>r</sup>.**

Consequently, **x<sup>r</sup> + y<sup>r</sup> > x + y = 1**. This means that **(x + y)<sup>r</sup> = 1<sup>r</sup> < x<sup>r</sup> + y<sup>r</sup>**. This proves the theorem for x + y = 1.

Because we could assume x + y = 1, without loss of generality, we know that (x+y)<sup>r</sup> < x<sup>r</sup> + y<sup>r</sup> whenever x and y are positive real numbers and r is a real number with 0 < r < 1.

*I am unable to the understand the above mentioned proof. I am also not able to relate the use of **without loss of generality** in this solution. As far as I understand, when the phrase “without loss of generality” is used in a proof, we assert that by proving one case of a theorem, no additional argument is required to prove other specified cases. I also doubt if the above proof is correct or not.*

**Note: The above question is an example in given in the book Discrete Mathematics and applications by Kenneth H. Rosen (Indian Adaptation by Kamala Krithivasan).**

Comment: I think you missed the $<$ symbol in the question?

Comment: @Michael ok thanks

Comment: One could first prove the special case $x+y=1$ and then handle the general case $x+y=t$ as shown, without referring to WLG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't how to make it more explicit than it is.

You suppose that $x+y=1$ because if it weren't, you can reduce it to this case and move on with the proof. If $x,t$ are any numbers, then $x+y=t$ for some $t$.

To be able to move on with the proof "without loss of generality" we must show that **if the theorem is true for the particular case**, this is if we have proved it for $x+y=1$, then we can apply it for $x+y=t$, reducing the general case to the particular.

How to go on with this reduction? The author says that if $x+y=t$ then $(x/t)+(y/t)=1$. Now, **if it is true that $(a+b)^r<a^r+b^r$ when $a+b=1$** (this is our ASSUMPTION), we can take $a=x/t, b=y/t$, which leave us with $(x/t+y/t)^r<(x/t)^r+(y/t)^r$. The final step: if we multiply both sides by $t^r$ we have $t^r(x/t+y/t)^r<t^r(x^r/t^r)+t^r(y^r/t^r)\implies [t(x/t+y/t)]]^r<t^r(x^r/t^r)+t^r(y^r/t^r)\implies (x+y)^r<x^r+y^r$.

We have proved the general case using the particular case when $x+y=1$, which we have used in our assumption. That particular case needs to be proved, otherwise the whole proof goes astray since it depends of it, and that's what the author does

Comment: thnx. Now I understand that,   here we first prove a particular case which is x + y =1 and then using it we prove for a more general case which is x + y = t.
Now could you tell me why here **without Loss of generality** is used. It could have been shown without it also. I am little bit confused with the use of **without Loss of Generality**

Comment: @NavneetSrivastava Do you mean why did the author use that expression? Because it's what it means.
See: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality
"The term is used before an assumption in a proof which narrows the premise to some special case; it implies that the proof for that case can be easily applied to all others, or that all other cases are equivalent or similar.Thus, given a proof of the conclusion in the special case, it is trivial to adapt it to prove the conclusion in all other cases."
Which is certainly what we have here. After the special case, the general follows easily.

Comment: thnx. If I understand correctly then, WLOG is like proving for one special case and then on that basis generalizing the prove for all other cases.

Comment: I would also like to know what are some easy incorrect uses of WLOG. If you can comment on that, I'll be glad.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think any cases like that come to mind. The cases that fail are the ones who don't success in doing the proof. If someone says "WLOG we can..." and proves a particular case, but the general case fails to be deduced from that particular case, there is indeed a loss of generality. Some textbooks have errors of this kind, assumptions are made such that the general case would follow easily, but it happens it is not the case. I don't remember any at the moment, but usually errors of this kind if not fixed appear at the end of the book, a section called "erratas" (like spivak).

Comment: Anyways thanks for your explanation and support.